# How to change the TypeORM config dynamically on a NestJS server?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to create an endpoint to configure my NestJS server. Basically, the endpoint will create my environment file(.env).

My problem is when I start my NestJS server for the first time I don't have the variables for the TypeORM, so when the TypeORM module is imported the server crash because it can find the configuration.

So I'm trying to find a way to start my NestJS server without importing the TypeORM module or importing the TypeORM without the configuration and add it later when I have the environment variables set.

mysql-database.module.ts

```js
...
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [MysqlDatabaseService],
  exports: [MysqlDatabaseService],
})
...
```

.env (That are the variables that are not set when I start the NestJS for the first time)

```
...
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = mysql
TYPEORM_HOST = localhost
TYPEORM_USERNAME = root
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = root
TYPEORM_DATABASE = mydb
TYPEORM_PORT = 3306
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = true
TYPEORM_LOGGING = true
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/**/*.entity.ts
```

Comment: When are you planning on setting your env variables? Why are they not available from the get-go?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel The idea is that the endpoint is who will create the .env file. This endpoint will work as a setup for the environment variables.

The same project will be used in different environments, so the idea is to simplify the configuration with a setup that will consume this endpoint.

Comment: Why not just fetch the `.env` file with curl?  Save it to the normal location where it can be loaded by typeorm. And just start the  nest.js server as you would normally do according to documentation. `npm run-script fetch-config &&  npm start`